# password_hash function giving blank results in database

Tags: php

im trying to get the password_hash function working for my newly created website but in my database i keep getting a blank result in the password section, this then results in my accounts not having any form of password so it will not log in is there something i have done wrong in this, here is my code and my verification code.

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['Register'])) {

        session_start();
        $FName = $_POST['First_Name'];
        $LName = $_POST['Last_Name'];
        $Email = $_POST['Email'];
        $PW = $_POST['Password'];

        $StorePass = password_hash($PW, PASSWORD_BCRYT, array('cost' => 10));

        $sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO `lpg-user-db` (Fname, Lname, Email, Password)Values('{$FName}', '{$LName}', '{$Email}', '{$StorePass}')");

        header('Location: Login.php');
    }
?>
```

Verification code :

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['Login'])) {

        $EM = $_POST['email'];
        $PW = $_POST['password'];

        $result = $con->query("select * from `lpg-user-db` where Email='$EM'");

        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

        if(password_verify($PW, $row['Password'] )) {

        session_start();

        $_SESSION["UserID"] = $row['UserID'];

        header('Location: Account.php');

        }else{
            session_start();
            $_SESSION["LoginFail"] = "Yes";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: did you do any debugging?

Comment: `PASSWORD_BCRYT` is a typo, it should read as `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` http://php.net/manual/en/password.constants.php. Make sure the password column is long enough to hold the hash also. 60-70 length, best to use 255 varchar. You will need to get rid of all old hashes and start over.

Comment: Hi there @Fred-ii- Saved me once again and it is now working and sorry davejal i had not, im really new to coding and need to do alot not reasearch into debugging and a few other things. Thanks for all the help guys Rob.

Comment: You're very much welcome.